# Getting an accurrate Results from Personality Test

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is wrong with this code, need ideas Thanks.
I have Used another Method which was fine for me, but my head of my Team said it was not Okay, because we needed one of the matched Results  of the user input to echo back after submit. so i come up with something like. but it still not working Okay.

```
 <?php
            //One of this should be my Results after input submited.
                $type = array(
                    0 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Du bist Weltenbummler"
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Luxusliebhaber"
                    ),
                    2 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Naturbursche/-madle"
                    ),
                    3 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Sunnyboy/-girl"
                    ),
                    4 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Wasserratte"
                    ),
                    5 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Wellnessliebhaber"
                    ),
                    6 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Adrenalinjunkie"
                    ),
                    7 => array(
                        "val" => 0,
                        "title" => "Städtebummler"
                    )
                );

    //this are my post data which is being looped to store the user input value
            $type = "";
            $current = 0;
            $exp = explode(',', $_POST['expenditure']);
           foreach($exp as $key => $arrE){
                $arrEx = $arrE;
               if($arrE < 300) {
                   $type[0]["val"] += 0;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 0.1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 0.3;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 1;

               }
                if($arrEx >= 300 && $arrEx <= 500) {
                   $type[0]["val"] += 0;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 1;

               }   
                  if($arrEx >= 600 && $arrEx <= 800) {
                   $type[0]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 1;

               } 
               if($arrEx >= 900 && $arrEx <= 1000) {
                   $type[0]["val"] += 2;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 1.3;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 1.5;

               }
               if($arrEx >= 1500 && $arrEx <= 3000) {
                   $type[0]["val"] += 2;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 0.7;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 1.3;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 2.2;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 2.1;

               }

           }
     $Season = explode(',', $_POST['seasonString']);
          foreach($Season as $key => $arrS){
               $arrSe = $arrS;
                if( $arrSe == "1"){
                   $type[0]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 0.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 2.0;} 
                if( $arrSe == "2"){
                   $type[0]["val"] += 0.5;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1.0;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 2.0;}
                if( $arrSe == "3"){             
                   $type[0]["val"] += 0.5;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 1.0;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 2.0;}
                if( $arrSe == "4"){
                    $type[0]["val"] += 0.5;
                   $type[1]["val"] += 1.1;
                   $type[2]["val"] += 1.4;
                   $type[3]["val"] += 0.5;
                   $type[4]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[5]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[6]["val"] += 2.0;
                   $type[7]["val"] += 2.0;
                }

                }



    for($i=0;$i<count($type);$i++){
     //First loop
            if($i == 0) {
                $title = $type[0]["title"];
                $current = $type[0]["val"];
            }

            if($type[$i]["val"] > $current) {
                $title = $type[$i]["title"];
            }

    }
    echo $type;

        ?>
```

Comment: Question needs a better introduction. What is the code supposed to do? What's not working?

Comment: Is a personality test which muss give me a matching results base on the user input. as i said the first Code with multid index array is where i got stacked. But the second which work fine i think but not accepted the team .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete guess ...

```
$index = 0;
$max = $type[0]["val"];

for($i=1; $i<count($type); $i++) {
    if($type[$i]["val"] > $max) {
        $index = $i;
        $max = $type[$i]["val"];
    }
}
echo "Du bist " . $type[$index]["title"];
```

or, even simpler :

```
$maxItem = $type[0];
for($i = 1; $i < count($type); $i++) {
    if($type[$i]["val"] > $maxItem["val"]) {
        $maxItem = $type[$i];
    }
}
echo "Du bist " . $maxItem["title"];
```

Comment: Thanks but it seams your code will only give me the max value from the user but not the "title", which is my problem. i was getting the max value but to get the results attached and echo on the page is my problem.

Comment: So please state in the question exactly what you want to be echoed.

Comment: Sorry again your code is absolute Okay and working perfect too. just proof it today, and Thanks a lot.